# An unexpected commit when creating a project with Vue CLI

Tags: git, vue-cli

I was just creating a new project with Vue CLI: `vue create test`

As I know, Vue CLI would create a git repo for me automatically.

It was successful. Then I entered the project and list the commits of the repo right after creating it:

```sh
$ cd test
$ git log
commit 7b36abb129c8a8119da95dbadf208ca34dbb5b32 (HEAD -> master)
Author: xxx <xxx@xxx.com>
Date:   Sat Jan 22 19:20:34 2022 +0800

    init
```

I'd like to know how to prevent Vue CLI from commiting automatically when creating a project.

Thanks for answering my question!

Note:

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

```sh
$ node -v
v16.13.2
$ npm -v
8.3.2
$ vue -V
@vue/cli 4.5.15
```

Comment: Why is that a problem? You can just remove or amend the commit.

Comment: I just wanna know why is there an initial commit committed automatically? Is that configured in the configuration file of Vue CLI?

Comment: What about `--git false` or `--no-git` ? https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#vue-create

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot.